# Search matches in array

Tags: arrays, angular, string, typescript

I am currently writing a simple program where i need to look if the entered input string is also in the array.

To make it simple
If a persons types 'Ai' i want the program to show everything in the array that contains the letters'Ai'. Result would be 'Airplane', 'Air', 'Airport', 'Airfield' etc.

Anyone knows how this is possible to make quickly and simple?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review the guidelines for [ask].  You might want to describe what you've already tried, and provide a [mre] of your issue.  Presumably the answer here is going to look like `arr.filter(s => s.startsWith(input))` or `arr.filter(s => s.includes(input))` or even something else depending on what you mean by "contains" (this is where being specific about use cases is helpful.  Does "air" match? Does "FAir" match? Does "Acid" match? etc), but without a [mre] it's hard to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're dealing with an array of all strings, then something like these functions should work:

```
// Check if any string in an array contains "str" as a substring.
function findStringThatContainsString(array: string[],str: string)
{
    let filteredArray = array.filter(x => x.includes(str));
    return filteredArray.length > 0;
}

// Check if any string in an array starts with "str."
function findStringThatStartsWithString(array: string[],str: string)
{
    let filteredArray = array.filter(x => x.startsWith(str));
    return filteredArray.length >0;
}
```

Test program:

```
let testString: string = "air";
let arr1 = ["corsair","stenographer"];
let arr2 = ["hey","no"];

function findStringThatContainsString(array: string[],str: string)
{
    let filteredArray = array.filter(x => x.includes(str));
    return filteredArray.length > 0;
}
function findStringThatStartsWithString(array: string[],str: string)
{
    let filteredArray = array.filter(x => x.startsWith(str));
    return filteredArray.length >0;
}
console.log(findStringThatContainsString(arr1,testString));
console.log(findStringThatContainsString(arr2,testString));
console.log(findStringThatStartsWithString(arr1,testString));
console.log(findStringThatStartsWithString(arr2,testString));
```

Output:

> true
> false
> false
> false